# Search Twitter by hour in R

Tags: r, api, twitter, analytics

Currently using the twitteR package and I am running into a roadblock to extract tweets by minute or hour. My ultimate goal is seeing the total number of tweets for a particular topic at a granular level (specifically for big events like Super Bowl or world cup).

The package allows tweets to be searched using `since` and `until`, but the most granularity one can get is by day.

Here is an example of the code:

```
tweets <- searchTwitter("grammy", n=1500, since='2016-02-15', until='2016-02-16')
```

Comment: Just checked and the limitation is actually in the API. __twitteR__ itself does not allow you to search with that kind of granularity. You can check out the source code [here](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR) which states that `searchTwitter()` does not accept `since` and `until` arguments down to hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: Can you show us what the result from `searchTwitter()` is? (The PDF they include is all kinds of terrible.)

Comment: @franklin.. the results doing a search for #rstats look like this `> tweets <- searchTwitter('#rstats', n=50)
>  head(tweets)
[[1]]
[1] "rquintino: Mairos_B #sqlsatportugal session: all about R in #SqlServer 2016 #rstats https://t.co/DHrqIZrz1e"

[[2]]
[1] "larysar: .yodacomplex my only nightmare is to process the list of lists structure of the bayesian draws #rstats"`

Comment: Have you considered using `sinceID` and `maxID`? Is a kind of indirect way, but if you have tweets that define your intervals well, you could use those. I don't know if that makes sense in your scenario. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the results by @SQLMenace it appears that twitteR only retrieves the status without returning accurate date/time information.

In that case, it depends on the scenario where you're performing the analysis. If you're performing the analysis "live" while the event is occurring you can simply run the R script as a CRONjob. Let's say every twenty minutes you run a job to get all the most recent tweets. Then you can eliminate duplicates to get an idea of how many unique tweets occurred in a 20 minute span.

However, if you're performing the analysis retrospectively, the above method wouldn't work. And I'd caution against using twitteR. It seems as though the functionality for gathering tweets by date is not that versatile. I'd recommend using tweepy (for Python) which retrieves not only the status, but also the exact time the tweet was sent.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. If I ran a job every 15 seconds for example, do you think I'd run into any issues accessing the Twitter API?

Comment: @coalcracker462 Probably not. You should check the rate limiting available on the Twitter RESTful API docs [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting). It says: "Search is rate limited at 180 queries per 15 minute window." So 1 query per 15 seconds will run you 60 queries in 15 minutes. Well below the 180 query limit.